# how to use AssertString() Addrouter() functions in CLIPS's dll of C++？

Tags: clips

i have used CLIPSWIN32.DLL in my program,and the functions in the dll is so limited.I even can not find the AssertString() Addrouter() functions in the dll.
the question is :
if there is a dll that contains the factions?
if not,is there a function that can repalce the twos above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download clipsnet from the CLIPS SourceForge Files area (http://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/), there are examples included that utilize the AssertString and AddRouter methods. Search the project to find the methods.

Comment: is there a function in C++ DLL similar with the AssertString and AddRouter methods in clipsnet DLL?Or can the Build method implement the same function?and how?

Comment: The latest version of the DLL can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/p/clipsrules/code/HEAD/tree/clipsdll/. It contains an AddRouter method. It does not contain an AssertString function. Since you have the DLL code, you can either add that method or just use the Eval function with an argument string of "(assert (fact))" rather than "(fact)" as you would use with AssertString.